# Add library (CLI11) downloaded form github using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to add a library to my c++ project. I have no idea how to do this
this is my project tree

```
├── build
├── build.sh
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── CLI11.hpp
└── src
    └── main.cc
```

and this is my cmakelists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

project(yup)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# add cli11

if (NOT DEFINED CLI11_DIR)
    set(CLI11_DIR "/usr/local/lib/CLI11" CACHE STRING "cli11 git repo")
endif()

# src/
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

include_directories(${CLI11_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)

add_executable(yup 
    src/main.cc
)

target_link_libraries(CLI11::CLI11)
```

why doesn't this work? Why in c++ it's so hard to add external dependecies?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you getting compiler/linker errors? CMake errors?

Comment: I just need guidance. I have no idea how to add a library cloned from github.

Comment: CLI11 is a header-only library so you should be able to simply copy the header into your `include` directory, which you appear to have done, then tell the compiler where to find the header file. Your CMake file appears to do that, but you shouldn't need any of the CLI11_DIR stuff at all.

Comment: fixed it. Had to remove the target_link_libraries call and add the hpp file to my includes folder. thanks for helping ;)